# How to check if commands inside the deployment.yaml are working?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm trying to write some bash commands inside my deployment.yaml file. I want to execute this commands at the postStart.

How can I check if the commands are working well? And if possible, how to get the node IP address?

```
  lifecycle:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command:
          - "sh"
          - "-c"
          - |
            GATEWAY_HTTPS_NAME="${GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME}_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS"
            GATEWAY_HTTPS_PORT=$(eval "echo \$$GATEWAY_HTTPS_NAME")
            cat /app/gateway/ip
            BOOL=true
            while [ $BOOL ]; do
               if [ "$GATEWAY_HTTPS_PORT" != '' ]; then
                  nohup sh -c "sleep 30; cat /app/gateway/ip | xargs -I[] curl  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}' -k https://[]/actuator/refresh" &
                  ROUTES=$(nohup sh -c "cat /app/gateway/ip | xargs -I[] curl  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}' -k https://[]/actuator/gateway/routes")
               else
                  nohup sh -c "sleep 30; cat /app/gateway/ip | xargs -I[] curl  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}' -k http://[]/actuator/refresh" &
                  ROUTES=$(nohup sh -c "cat /app/gateway/ip | xargs -I[] curl  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}' -k http://[]/actuator/gateway/routes")
               fi
               NODE_IP=???
               echo $ROUTES
               if [ $ROUTES[*] =~ $NODE_IP ]; then
                  BOOL=$false
               fi
               BOOL=$false
               sleep 10
            done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @vibiquin, I recommend being more specific with your question, by saying `And if possible, how to get the node IP address?` I couldn't understand, where you want to get that IP from, how you want to do that, and what are you going to do with it so I get a better idea about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the command using exit status, I usually do that by adding a double pipe which will output the exit status if something went wrong, here is an example:

```sh
ls /unexistant/dir &>/dev/null && echo Success, Code=$? || echo Something went wrong, Code=$?
```

This will obviously throw an error and run the commands after double pipe since the status code `not equals 0` will return **Something went wrong, Code=2**

Instead, if we run this:

```sh
ls /existant/dir &>/dev/null && echo Success, Code=$? || echo Something went wrong, Code=$?
```

This will run the first command with success and exit status will be 0 which means success, this is the output: **Success, Code=0**

You can of course play around with this and read more about double pipe